# Kafka console Consume Command not accepting bootstrap-servers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have installed Kafka on my windows machine. My Kafka version is kafka_2.12-2.4.0.
I have started the Zookeeper server, then Kafka server then creates the topic and then produces the message to created Topic. Till here everything is fine.
But when I run the Consume command, it is giving me below error.

> '--bootstrap-servers' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

I am using the below command.

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-servers localhost:9092 --topic TEST_TOPIC --from-beginning
```

Please suggest me what could be the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a typo

Answer (score 2):

You should use `--bootstrap-server` instead of `--bootstrap-servers` (note 's' at the end):

Try:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.bat \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --topic TEST_TOPIC \
    --from-beginning
```

Comment: Tried this also but same issue.\n.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TEST_TOPIC --from-beginning
'--bootstrap-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have this exact same issue and receiving the same error message even when using --bootstrap-server. I was following a tutorial which was done on a Mac and I am on Windows 10. Not sure if that could be related. I tried using the bat inside the windows folder for kafka download and that didn't help either 
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic myTopic

Comment: I posted an answer of what finally fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue on my side. The issue was that in the command prompt, for some reason, I had a double arrow >>:

C:\kafka_2.13-2.4.0>**>** .\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic myTopic
'--bootstrap-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Once I removed the double arrow, the error went away. Now I appear to have other issues where Kafka is not running on the port I thought it was, but that is a separate issue.

Comment: Hi Snowleopard you are right there was double arrow in the command.Now command is not giving error but the messages are not showing,even messages are publishing and i can see those messages in storage.see below command.C:\ttt\Softwares\kafka_2.12-2.4.0>.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TEST_TOPIC --from-beginning

C:\tttt\Softwares\kafka_2.12-2.4.0>

Comment: Your next issue could possibly be that  your kafka-console-consumer.bat is empty. Please see the answer I provided in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60303772/1451762